# removing white space in XML tags

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming XML which is having white space like:

`< /ns1:pr>` and `< /soapenv:Envelope>`

Because of this white space my XSLT fails to process. Is there any way we can omit those white space?

Incoming XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:pr xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
   <ns1:dis>
    <TP memberID="121897679001" FirstName="Tom" LastName="regen" auId="42424234">     
    </TP>
   </ns1:dis>
  < /ns1:pr>
 </soapenv:Body>
< /soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: "*Is there any way we can omit those white space?*" Not in XSLT, because XSLT cannot process your input.

Answer (score 1):

Don't refer to the input as "incoming XML" because it's not XML. No XML tools will process this. You have a choice

(a) fix the bug in the software that produced or corrupted this input, so that you're dealing with well-formed XML, or

(b) repair the incoming non-XML to make it well-formed.

Since well-formed XML can never have whitespace after a "<" character except in comments or processing instructions or CDATA sections where it's hopefully not important, it should be safe enough to do the repair using something like SED, replacing anything that matches `<\s+` with `<`. But fixing the bug would be far better.